# How to create a dummy dataframe from two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dummy-variable

lets say I have the dataframe:

```
a|stg1
a|stg2
a|stg3
b|stg2
b|stg3
c|stg1
```

and I would like to get a dataframe with dummies like this:

```
  stg1|stg2|stg3
a|  1 |  1 |  1
b|  0 |  1 |  1
c|  1 |  0 |  0
```

I have tried to use the get_dummies from pandas, but it doesn't do the trick
I also tried to create a dictionary with two for loops, ad even though it works, it takes forevery, and there must be a more elegant and efficient solution for that.

Or maybe it's more of a pivot table kind of thing? But then what function should I use?
each value pair is unique

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) which forms a frequency table by default:

```
# 0 is the column name of `a, b, c` and 1 is that of `stg*`
>>> res = pd.crosstab(df[0], df[1])
>>> res

1  stg1  stg2  stg3
0
a     1     1     1
b     0     1     1
c     1     0     0
```

`1` and `0` on top left are the name of the columns in the original dataframe; they become the names of the index & columns of the result. If they are not needed:

```
>>> res = res.rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
>>> res

   stg1  stg2  stg3
a     1     1     1
b     0     1     1
c     1     0     0
```

Comment: @biohazard90 glad to be of help! If you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/791774) one of the answers here to signal others that the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a common pivot table ('A' and 'B' are your column names):

```
pv = pd.pivot_table(df, index='A', columns='B', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
pv.index.name=None
pv.columns.name=None

print(pv)
```

Output:

```
   stg1  stg2  stg3
a   1.0   1.0   1.0
b   0.0   1.0   1.0
c   1.0   0.0   0.0
```